# Best way to use value generated by thread on different class

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a main class and two more classes and a thread. When thread finish executing, that result should be available for all three classes. So basically like a trigger function. What solution would match this problem?

Comment: Another class should act as a container for the result.

Comment: @meskobalazs but how do you prefer to notify other classes that the execution is fiished

Comment: You could use the Observer pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern The page even has example Java code.

Comment: Please provide more info and sample code that shows: Are the other threads (that use the information) already running? Do they wait for the one thread to finish? If yes, how is that done? If no, when/how do they expect the new result? etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A working, simple example could look like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class MainClass implements ResultReceiver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SeparateThread separateThread = new SeparateThread();
        separateThread.registerForResult(new MainClass());
        separateThread.registerForResult(new OtherClass1());
        separateThread.registerForResult(new OtherClass2());
        separateThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void receive(String result) {
        System.out.println("MainClass.receive(\"" + result + "\")");
    }

}

class SeparateThread extends Thread {

    private static final Collection<ResultReceiver> receivers = new ArrayList<>();

    public void registerForResult(ResultReceiver receiver) {
        receivers.add(receiver);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String result = "Hello" + " " + "world";

        for (ResultReceiver receiver : receivers) {
            receiver.receive(result);
        }
    }

}

class OtherClass2 implements ResultReceiver {

    @Override
    public void receive(String result) {
        System.out.println("OtherClass2.receive(\"" + result + "\")");
    }

}

class OtherClass1 implements ResultReceiver {

    @Override
    public void receive(String result) {
        System.out.println("OtherClass1.receive(\"" + result + "\")");
    }

}

interface ResultReceiver {
    void receive(String result);
}
```

However waiting for the result and handle all results in the main Thread (more complex solution) is in most cases more relyable.

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep list of objects which are required to been notified inside the Thread. Notify them i.e. call a method or set a Boolean value in all of those classes once the thread finished executing.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple solution is to use Thread.wait() and Thread.notifyAll():

Worker class (also Main class) starts handlers and worker. Worker waits 1 second and then 'publishes' the result via notifyAll();

```
public class Worker extends Thread {

    private String result;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        result = "Result " + System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Worker has result:" + result);

        synchronized (this) {
            notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Worker worker = new Worker();

        new Handler("Handler 1", worker).start();
        new Handler("Handler 2", worker).start();
        new Handler("Handler 3", worker).start();

        worker.start();
    }
}
```

Handler class waits for result and prints it:

```
public class Handler extends Thread {

    private final String name;
    private final Worker worker;

    public Handler(final String name, final Worker worker) {
        this.name = name;
        this.worker = worker;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        synchronized (worker) {
            try {
                System.out.println(name + " waiting for worker...");
                worker.wait();
            } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(name + " result: " + worker.getResult());
        }
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
Handler 1 waiting for worker...
Handler 3 waiting for worker...
Handler 2 waiting for worker...
Worker has result:Result 1422364603864
Handler 2 result: Result 1422364603864
Handler 3 result: Result 1422364603864
Handler 1 result: Result 1422364603864
```

Comment: I assumed OP meant a separate thread next to the main thread. The scenario described really suggests a woker/handler set up like above in my opinion. Otherwise the solution could simply be to set the result on the two classes after the result is obtained.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to force 3 classes or any number of classes, to wait for result is, use CyclicBarrier. But this not what you said in your last line that is trigger kind of effect.

```
public class ResultThread implements Runnable{
    private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    private String result;

    public String getResult() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("GetResult...");
        latch.await();
        System.out.println("Got Result ...");
        return result;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();        }
        result = " Thread done at " + System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("result calculated");
        latch.countDown();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ResultThread rThread = new ResultThread();
        new Thread(rThread).start();
        System.out.println(rThread.getResult());
    }
}
```

For Trigger kind of this replace the Latch with Lock.wait and notifyAll

```
public class ResultThread implements Runnable{
    private Lock resultLock = new ReentrantLock();
    private volatile boolean resultDone = false;
    private String result;

    public String getResult() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("GetResult...");
        if(!resultDone){
            synchronized (resultLock){
                System.out.println("Waiting...");
                resultLock.wait();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Got Result ...");
        return result;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();        }
        result = " Thread done at " + System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("result calculated");
        resultDone = true;
        synchronized (resultLock){
            resultLock.notifyAll();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ResultThread rThread = new ResultThread();
        new Thread(rThread).start();
        System.out.println(rThread.getResult());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a singleton classe and use it as a container:

```
public class ClassicSingleton {
  private static ClassicSingleton instance = null;
  private String text;
 // Add your values 
  protected ClassicSingleton() {

}
public void setText(String text){
 this.text=text;
}
public static ClassicSingleton getInstance() {
  if(instance == null) {
     instance = new ClassicSingleton();
  }
  return instance;
  }
}
```

And then you can call it in your thread like:

```
ClassSingleton singleton = getInstance();
singleton.setText("something");
```

Comment: No reason why it should be a singleton.

Comment: Agreed, the question was *best way*, and Singleton is probably the *worst possible way* :)

Comment: Btw. your singleton is not threadsafe. Not a good example for inter-thread-communication...

Comment: And it lacks a notification mechanism.